# How does one expose a memory managed item that must be closed/deleted as an importable resource in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have an item that interfaces with a C library.  The interface allocates memory.

The `__del__` method takes care of everything, but there is no guarantee the `__del__` method will be called in an imperative python3 runtime.

So, I have overloaded the context manager functions and can declare my item 'with':

```
with Foo(**kwargs) as foo:
  foo.doSomething()

# no memory leaks
```

However, I am now exposing my `foo` in an `__init__.py`, and am curious how I could possibly expose the context manager object in a way that allows a user to use it without using it inside of a 'with' block.

Is there a way I can open/construct my `Foo` inside my module such that there is a guarantee `__del__` will be called (or the context manager exit function) so that it is exposed for use, but doesn't expose a daemon or other long term process to risk of memory loss?

---

Or is deletion implied when an object is constructed implicitly via import, even though it ~may or may not~ occur when the object is constructed in the runtime scope?

Comment: What does: `exposing my foo` mean?

Comment: @quamrana if you see the line `with Foo(**kwargs) as foo`, there is this thing I have constructed called `foo`.  Now, what I would like to do is expose that thing I have constructed for importation from outside of the module's scope.

Comment: @quamrana such that it is guaranteed to get cleaned up, just like it would when constructed via the `with` mechanic.

Comment: Ok, you can't have it both ways. Either you use the `with` and context management to ensure `__del__`, or you construct it without, exposing foo, but losing any guarantees of deletion.

Comment: @quamrana so the user must magically know they must always `with` this thing? That's irritating.  there must be some `__really_del__` overload we can define going forward.

Comment: That's how it works. Users know that you can have: `with open(name) as foo:` and `foo` will be cleaned up at the end of the block. You could invert everything and call a function with a callback, and the function makes your `foo` inside a `with`, but calls the callback before the end of the `with`.

Comment: @quamrana this defeats the purpose, as the interface needs to be declared once to avoid disk-IO overhead per-call. That means **one** with at **one** scope.  I'd really rather not impart the requirement to know the object must be used 'with' scope.

Comment: Its quite simple: When do you want your object to be deleted? Does your user know when that will be? You don't want them to access it after its been deleted.

Comment: @quamrana I think I am just going to try importing it without `with` and see if, in practice, it ever leaks.  Or whether it actually gets deleted when it is imported from a module pre-constructed.

Comment: I think you are conflating `import` and construction. These are separate concepts.

Comment: @quamrana no, I am not.  You can import pre constructed items **as a resource**.  For example, I can declare `foo = Foo(...)` insde of a file `foo.py`.  Then I can import that item, `from foo import foo`.  This is different than importing the class `Foo` and constructing it in the runtime context.

Comment: @quamrana the question amounts to: does the wishy-washy ambiguous deletion protocol apply to objects constructed beneath the main scope -- and my **guess** is that it is possible that it does not.   So I am just going to try, since it appears there is no way to avoid that work and manage the object's expiration from interior scope directly.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying. But, yes objects you construct in, say, `foo.py` have the same natural lifetime (assuming the module is imported) as if they were constructed in your main module.

Comment: @quamrana got it.  Guess my plan doesn't change, eventually what ever thing I expose finally has to manage the deletion and be used `with` scope.  Thanks for the patience -- this was a tricky semantic overload via text.

Comment: @quamrana however, in practice, it seems that in fact delete is called.

Comment: @Chris No, there is no difference there -- those **both happen in a runtime context**. Anyway, In pretty much all similar circumstances, the way this is handled is *explicitly documenting* that the object requires  cleanup. Usually, you have some method `def cleanup` (or `def close`) which gets called in `__exit__`. The user can choose to take the responsibility of handling that, or they can use the object as a context manager.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga seems that it does get called.  Either way, I have defined just about everything I could have on this object to trigger delete and exiting.  So perhaps I solved in some unknown way by doing the right thing accidentally.

Comment: @Chris no, you are *definitely doing it wrong*. You are relying on CPython implementation details, but basically, you should not rely on an object's `__del__` being called if the object exists when the interpreter exists, again, [this is explicitly warned against in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am not relying on __del__ alone.  In the question description, it is clear that I have also defined the context manager overloads.

Answer (score 0):

Although this should probably not be the case, or at least might not always be the case from version to version...

...Python3.9 does indeed call `__del__` on objects initialized prior to importation.

I can't accept this answer because I have no way of directly proving that it is not possible python3 does not call the `__del__`, but it has not failed to call it so far, whereas I get a memory leak every time I do not dispose the object properly after declaring it during runtime flow.

Comment: The import really really is irrelevant here. It seems like you are trying to rely on the `__del__` method being called for an object that exists at the time of interpreter exit ... this is *explicitly not guaranteed*. If it *happens* to work, then you are relying on an implementation detail. The correct way is to provide a context-manager interface and *document that it should be used this way*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have defined and documented the context manager usage, but it seems that after defining and documenting everything, it just works anyways.

Comment: This is really a wrongheaded approach. This may or may not work on different versions of CPython. Your code has a bug. You really shouldn't rely on this behavior. More importantly, as stated, **this has nothing to do with imports**

Comment: This is not a wrong-headed approach.  It is an approach by induction.  Since it has been deleted every time so far, it will likely be deleted every time thereafter.  I don't *know* that it will be, and I've acknowledged that I cannot *know* that it will be.  I have also done everything warranted by your rec already.  So, I mean, it looks like you are repeating what I have said, just reframing it in a negative context.

Comment: Fine man. Enjoy tracking down resource leaks in another Python version, or when the interpreter happens to handle the final cleanup slightly differently due to various arcane vagaries that can occur when interacting with other modules.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga and again, I have pointed out that would be the result here.   This is the quote where I address that issue: "Although this should probably not be the case, or at least might not always be the case from version to version...".  It is **the first sentence of my answer**.